# Ignite Jdbc SQL COPY FROM command executing but not importing data

Tags: ignite

I have a java code that exports data from postgresql into a csv file and then uses ingnite COPY FROM to import into ignite tables.

```
// PROCESSING THE FIRST TABLE
String copySql = "copy (" +
        "select ..... from postgresql_table_1 " +
        ") to stdout csv";
//postgresql jdbc copymanager
copyManager.copyOut(copySql, writer1);

//igniteStatement from an ignite connection
igniteStatement.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ignite_table_1");
igniteStatement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE ignite_table_1 (" +
        "    col1 INT(11), " +
        "    col2 VARCHAR(255), " +
        "    ....., " +
        "    PRIMARY KEY (id) " +
        ") WITH \"template=partitioned\"");

igniteStatement.executeUpdate("COPY FROM '" + postgresql_table_1_csv_path + "' " +
        "INTO ignite_table_1(.....) " +
        "FORMAT CSV");

// PROCESSING THE SECOND TABLE
copySql = "copy " +
        "(" +
        "with days as (select generate_series('" + startDate + "'::date, current_date, '1 day') as day) " +
        "select row_number() over (order by days.day) as id, " +
        "to_char(days.day::date,'YYYY-MM-DD') as date_of_... " +
        "   from days" +
        ") to stdout csv";

copyManager.copyOut(copySql, writer2);

igniteStatement.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ignite_table_2");
igniteStatement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE ignite_table_2 (" +
        "    id INT(11), " +
        "    date_of_... DATE, " +
        "    ..... INT(11), " +
        "    PRIMARY KEY (id) " +
        ") WITH \"template=partitioned\"");

igniteStatement.executeUpdate("COPY FROM '" + second_table_path + "' " +
        "INTO ignite_table_2(id, date_of_....) " +
        "FORMAT CSV");
```

THE CODE RUNS FINE AS FOLLOWS

1. The first csv file is generated successfully
2. The first copy from .. into for ignite_table_1 succeeds and is populated with the data from the csv. It can also be seen in control center.
3. The second csv file is also generated successfully
4. The second copy from... into ignite_table_2 executes successfully without exceptions

The issue I am having is that though (4) completed. The ignite_table_2 is empty when the program completed. Thought there is data matching the columns specified in the second csv file.

What could be the problem?. There are no exception reported neither from the java program nor in the ignite log.

Comment: I tried to use sqlline promt to execute the second copy from..into command and it loaded the data into the table. how come the one from the jdbc api, this one `igniteStatement.executeUpdate("COPY FROM 'second_table_path' INTO ignite_table_2(id, date_of_....) FORMAT CSV);` not working

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to resolve this. The issue was that the `Writer` used by the jdbc postgresql copyManager was still open while attempting to execute `copy from...csv...into` on the ignite table.

Closing the writers before doing the copy, resolved it.